# Create 3 row columns with horizontal scroll in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, emulation

UPDATE: I keep getting an error when i try and use a listView pretty much i need 3 list view on 3 layers of columns and each has a horizontal scrollable list view

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget horizontalList1 = new Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      child: new ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(width: 130.0, color: Colors.red,),
      ],
    )
    );

    Widget horizontalList2 = new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
        child: new ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(width: 130.0, color: Colors.blue,),
      ],
    )
    );
    Widget horizontalList3 = new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
        child: new ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(width: 130.0, color: Colors.blue,),
      ],
    )
    );


    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Activity"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container(
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: <Widget>[
              horizontalList1,
              horizontalList2,
              horizontalList3,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

So pretty much this should work but i keep getting a mediaquery error and have no clue what i am missing or what's causing the error

Comment: Have you tried using 3 list views with horizontal scroll axis in a column?

Comment: Well i wasn't sure if that would work pretty much i need to have 3 rows of like 5 or 10 items scroll able will a list work for that ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a `ListView` inside another `ListView` the first one should have a specific size

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      Widget horizontalList1 = new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
        height: 200, //<- Here the height should be specific
        child: new ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 130.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
         ],
       ));

     Widget horizontalList2 = new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
        height: 200,//<- Here the height should be specific
        child: new ListView(
           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
           children: <Widget>[
             Container(
               width: 130.0,
               color: Colors.blue,
              ),
          ],
        ));
     Widget horizontalList3 = new Container(
       margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
       height: 200,//<- Here the height should be specific
        child: new ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
           children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 130.0,
              color: Colors.blue,
             ),
          ],
    ));

 return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("Activity"),
  ),
  body: new Center(
    child: new Container(
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          horizontalList1,
          horizontalList2,
          horizontalList3,
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Your error says `MediaQuery.of() was called on a context that does not contain a MediaQuery`
It's Because You are using `Scaffold` for your app's parent widget.But `scaffold` should be used for a page not an app.
You should use `MaterialApp` for the parent widget of your app.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
          home:Scaffold(
          //Your code here
          )
      );
  }
```